# Why do projects like angular have their own version of common functions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to understand or refresh my logic on this better - for example in angular it has the angular.forEach().

I thought it was because the code in a controller(or module in general) - didn't have access to the browser api (functions and objects, etc) - and for that matter the forEach function of the browser.

But just tested it out as I was trying to understand it better/prove rationale - and both of these console.log() expressions worked.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('JCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.test = 'scope and binding works'; 

    [0, 1, 4].forEach(function(value) {
      console.log(value);
    });
    console.log([].forEach);
}]);
```

here is the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/LEQjpdmyzzJwAjLdhOpI?p=preview)

Comment: Because they include angular components like $digest() where the standard javascript would not. Same with $timeout, $interval, etc.

Comment: I think the answer is twofold: One, not all browsers support all functions and it's necessary to shim some of those functions if they are used with any frequency in the library; and two, nobody wants to have to maintain dependencies on other libraries. Everyone *could* just use (say) Underscore.js to polyfill `Array.prototype.forEach`, but then they have to track the Underscore library and deal with issues accordingly. Much simpler to just maintain it within each library, from the maintainers' perspective.

Comment: It doesn't apply in this case to Angular's for-each loop but broadly speaking many libraries will expand on the out of the box behaviour.  For [example](http://jsfiddle.net/m1ry2m79/1/) many implementation will let you `return <boolean>` in the callback to exit the loop - similar to `break` and `continue` in the classical `for` control structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directly from github source code of Angular.js that you can find [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/09ee82d84dcbea4a6e8d85903af82dcd087a78a7/src/Angular.js)

````
/**
* @ngdoc function
* @name angular.forEach
* @module ng
* @kind function
*
* @description
* Invokes the `iterator` function once for each item in `obj` collection, which can be either an
* object or an array. The `iterator` function is invoked with `iterator(value, key, obj)`, where `value`
* is the value of an object property or an array element, `key` is the object property key or
* array element index and obj is the `obj` itself. Specifying a `context` for the function is optional.
*
* It is worth noting that `.forEach` does not iterate over inherited properties because it filters
* using the `hasOwnProperty` method.
*
* Unlike ES262's
* [Array.prototype.forEach](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18),
* Providing 'undefined' or 'null' values for `obj` will not throw a TypeError, but rather just
* return the value provided.
*
  ```js
    var values = {name: 'misko', gender: 'male'};
    var log = [];
    angular.forEach(values, function(value, key) {
      this.push(key + ': ' + value);
    }, log);
    expect(log).toEqual(['name: misko', 'gender: male']);
  ```
*
* @param {Object|Array} obj Object to iterate over.
* @param {Function} iterator Iterator function.
* @param {Object=} context Object to become context (`this`) for the iterator       function.
* @returns {Object|Array} Reference to `obj`.
*/
````

So, as you can see

> Unlike ES262's [Array.prototype.forEach](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18), providing 'undefined' or 'null' values for `obj` will not throw a TypeError, but rather just return the value provided.

These kind of things are done because when you design your own system, there is a high possibility that you will need something more other than the original.

Comment: a lot of great clarifications and answers given  - thanks - i picked this one - because it helped me find the answer relative to the angular project in the source code.

Answer (score 2):

Its usually for optimization, standardization and backward compatibility they are providing an api for iterating a loop that will work " in any environment " so you wont have to relay on other frameworks to do that

In your example forEach (if i am not mistaken is not supported by IE8) so instead of using some outside library or whatnot. you can use angulars

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Array.forEach` in IE8 - it doesn't work.

Javascript frameworks generally have two main purposes:

1. Give you helper functions to let you do common or complicated tasks, such as animation, searching the DOM etc.
2. Provide a consistent API so you don't need to worry about browser compatibility.

It is point 2 that is of note here. If you had to check each time you wanted to use a "standard" function and work around it if it does not exist, your code would be more messy and hard to read, e.g. compare:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];

if(arr.forEach)
{
    arr.forEach(function(v,i) {
        // do domething
    })
}
else
{
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var val = arr[i];
        // do something
    }
}
```

with

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];

angular.forEach(arr, function(value, key) {
  // do something
});
```

In fact, internally many frameworks will check if the built-in method exists and use that, and only use its custom implementation if required.

Point 1 is also relevant here in that for example `Array.forEach` only works with Arrays whereas `Angular.forEach` will iterate through arrays *and* object properties in the same way, so it is providing extra functionality to the base Javascript implementation.